# How to get javascript array elements into the html form field as a value through a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am having 6 bootstrap cards where the details of the card are id, image, content.on clicking the card I am getting the details of the card into the local storage and from that, I am extracting the ids into another array named styleIds I want these styleIds values to sent as value to the input field as onload of body 
My js code:

```
var styles = []
var styleIds = []
function getStyle(id) {
    if (styles.length > 0) {
        var data = { id: id, image: $("#img_"+id).attr('src'),content: $("#cont_" + id).text() }
        var x = JSON.stringify(data)
        var index = styles.indexOf(x)
        if (index == -1) {
            styles.push(x)
        }
        else {
            styles.splice(index, 1)
        }
    }
    else {
        var data = { id: id, image: $("#img_"+id).attr('src'),content: $("#cont_" + id).text() }
        var x = JSON.stringify(data)
        styles.push(x)
    }
    localStorage.setItem("styles", JSON.stringify(styles))
    styleIds = styles.map(element => JSON.parse(element).id);
    console.log(styleIds)
    assample();
}
function assample() {
    $("#style").val(styleIds);
    console.log(styleIds)
}
function initStyles() {
  var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("styles") || '[]');
  styleIds = storedNames.map(element => JSON.parse(element).id);
}
```

My form code is:

```
<body onload = "sample();initGoals();issample();assample();initStyles();">

              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="room" id="name" value=" ">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group" >
                <input type="text" name="goal" id="goal" value=" ">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group" >
                <input type="text" name="style" id="style" value=" ">
              </div>


              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" required>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password2">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required>
              </div>

              <input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">
            </form>
```

The cards are on one page and the form is the another web page so in the styles page the styleIds array is getting the ids butwhen I navigate to the form page the values are getting as a value for the field in the form what is the mistake I did?

Comment: I think you're calling the functions in an incorrect order, try calling `initStyles()` first and then `assample()` in the body onload.

Comment: Ya ur right give it as an answer i will aceept it @ Ramesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're calling the functions in the correct order. Also, I would suggest renaming your function names so that you don't get confused.

You can change your `onload` to just call one function and later care about the order.

```
<body onload = "doSomething()">
```

and in the script:

```
function doSomething() {
    sample();
    initGoals();
    issample();
    initStyles();
    assample();
}
```